# How could I add a coin that spawns above the static platforms in this game?

Tags: python, pygame

I started learning Python and Pygame recently, and I decided to make a game for practice. I copied a big part of my code from a similar game, but now that I want to modify it, I can't get the hang of it. I'm trying to add a coin or an orb to my game, that spawns only in the first type of platform, and that has a "rare" chance of spawning. Once collected, it will increase the score.
Any help is welcomed!

```
class NoobieJumper:                     #https://github.com/f-prime/DoodleJump
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
        self.green = pygame.image.load("images/cloudA.png").convert_alpha()
        self.score = 0
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 25)
        self.blue = pygame.image.load("images/cloudB.png").convert_alpha()
        self.red = pygame.image.load("images/cloudB.png").convert_alpha()
        self.playerRight = pygame.image.load("images/right.png").convert_alpha()
        self.playerRight_1 = pygame.image.load("images/right_1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.playerLeft = pygame.image.load("images/left.png").convert_alpha()
        self.playerLeft_1 = pygame.image.load("images/left_1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.orbSprite = pygame.image.load("images/orb.png").convert_alpha()
        self.direction = 0
        self.playerx = 400
        self.playery = 400
        self.platforms = [[400, 500, 0, 0]]
        self.scor = [pygame.Rect(100, 250, 50, 50)]
        self.cameray = 0
        self.jump = 0
        self.gravity = 0
        self.xmovement = 0
    
    def updatePlayer(self):
        if not self.jump:        
            self.playery += self.gravity
            self.gravity += 1
        elif self.jump:
            self.playery -= self.jump
            self.jump -= 1
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[K_RIGHT]:
            if self.xmovement < 10:
                self.xmovement += 1
            self.direction = 0

        elif key[K_LEFT]:
            if self.xmovement > -10:
                self.xmovement -= 1
            self.direction = 1
        else:
            if self.xmovement > 0:
                self.xmovement -= 0.5
            elif self.xmovement < 0:
                self.xmovement += 0.5
        if self.playerx > 840:
            self.playerx = -40
        elif self.playerx < -40:
            self.playerx = 840
        self.playerx += self.xmovement
        if self.playery - self.cameray <= 200:
            self.cameray -= 10
        if not self.direction:
            if self.jump:
                self.screen.blit(self.playerRight_1, (self.playerx, self.playery - self.cameray))
            else:
                self.screen.blit(self.playerRight, (self.playerx, self.playery - self.cameray))
        else:
            if self.jump:
                self.screen.blit(self.playerLeft_1, (self.playerx, self.playery - self.cameray))
            else:
                self.screen.blit(self.playerLeft, (self.playerx, self.playery - self.cameray))

    def updatePlatforms(self):
        for p in self.platforms:
            rect = pygame.Rect(p[0], p[1], self.green.get_width() - 10, self.green.get_height())
            player = pygame.Rect(self.playerx, self.playery, self.playerRight.get_width() - 10, self.playerRight.get_height())
            if rect.colliderect(player) and self.gravity and self.playery < (p[1] - self.cameray):
                if p[2] != 2:
                    self.jump = 15
                    self.gravity = 0
                else:
                    p[-1] = 1
            if p[2] == 1:
                if p[-1] == 1:
                    p[0] += 5
                    if p[0] > 550:
                        p[-1] = 0
                else:
                    p[0] -= 5
                    if p[0] <= 0:
                        p[-1] = 1

    def drawPlatforms(self):
        for p in self.platforms:
            check = self.platforms[1][1] - self.cameray
            if check > 600:
                platform = random.randint(0, 1000)
                if platform < 800:
                    platform = 0
                elif platform < 900:
                    platform = 1
                else:
                    platform = 2

                self.platforms.append([random.randint(0, 700), self.platforms[-1][1] - 50, platform, 0])
                coords = self.platforms[-1]
                #check = random.randint(0, 1000)
                self.platforms.pop(0)
                self.score += 100
            if p[2] == 0:
                self.screen.blit(self.green, (p[0], p[1] - self.cameray))
            elif p[2] == 1:
                self.screen.blit(self.blue, (p[0], p[1] - self.cameray))
            elif p[2] == 2:
                self.screen.blit(self.red, (p[0], p[1] - self.cameray))

    def scorOrbs(self):
        for o in self.scor:
            screen.blit(orbSprite, (o[0], o[1]))
            '''orb = random.randint(0, 6)
            if orb == 0:
                scor = 1
            else:
                scor = 0
            self.scor.append'''

    def generatePlatforms(self):
        on = 600
        while on > -100:
            x = random.randint(0,700)
            platform = random.randint(0, 1000)
            if platform < 770:
                platform = 0
            elif platform < 900:
                platform = 1
            else:
                platform = 2
            self.platforms.append([x, on, platform, 0])
            on -= 50

    def drawBack(self):
        screen.blit(background, [0, 0])

    def restart(self):
        self.cameray = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.platforms = [[400, 500, 0, 0]]
        self.generatePlatforms()
        self.playerx = 400
        self.playery = 400
        pygame.display.flip()
    
    def run(self):
        running = True
        lost = False
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.generatePlatforms()
        while running:
            self.screen.fill(BLACK)
            clock.tick(60)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_r:
                        lost = False
                        self.restart()
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        lost = False
                        self.restart()
                        running = False
            
            if self.playery - self.cameray > 600:
                lost = True

            if lost == False:
                self.drawBack()
                self.drawPlatforms()
                self.updatePlayer()
                self.updatePlatforms()
                self.screen.blit(self.font.render(str(self.score), -1, (0, 0, 0)), (25, 22))
                pygame.display.flip()
            else:
                screen.blit(loser, [0, 0])
                points = font_L.render (str(self.score), True, BLACK)
                screen.blit(points, [540, 445])
                pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should have 1 well-described problem and question. This question concerns several vaguely described problems. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, you want to cerate a Doodle Jump game and you want to spawn a coin on random places in your map (atop the platform). So you have to take the code where you spawn a platform: `self.platforms.append([random.randint(0, 700), self.platforms[-1][1] - 50, platform, 0])`
And also spawn a coin on  top of it. Now I see that the platform `list` contains `Rect`s . You can do the same with coins, but with a coin image this time.
You should first create a group for the coins, eg. `self.coins = []` in the `__init__` method of your class.
Then, whenever you create a platform, spawn a coin on top of it (with rarity) like this:

```
if p[2] == 0 and random.randint(0, 10) == 0:   # check if the platform is green and whether the coin should spawn
    self.coins.append(coin_img, coords[0], coords[1] - 25, coin_img.get_rect(x=coords[0], y=coords[1] - 25))  # you must append the image and the position, so it can be drawn later (coin_img is your coin asset and the 'coords' variable is the position of the platform the coin is about to be placed, and the last argument is the `Rect` so we can check for collision later on)
```

Then create a new method called `drawCoins`:

```
def drawCoins(self):
    for coin in self.coins:
        self.screen.blit(coin[0], coin[1], coin[2] - self.cameray)  # coin[0] is the image, coin[1] is the x-position and coin[2] is the y-position (with the camera-y offset)
```

And call it in the loop:

```
if not lost:      # you can replace 'if lost == False' by 'if not lost'
    self.drawCoins()
    self.updateCoins()
```

Where `updateCoins` is checking for collision, like so:

```
def updateCoins(self):
    for coin in self.coins[:]:
        if coin[3].colliderect(player):
            self.coins.remove(coin)
            self.score += 100  # or any amount
    self.coins = [coin for coin in self.coins if coin[3].bottom < 600]  # remove all coins from the list whose bottom is higher than 600 (they are off the screen)
```

Although this may be helpful, it's very bare-bones and you should tweak some values as the code you put in the question is not commented/documented and this is the best I can do.